# Read the Data inside a single Sheet inside .xlsx file using Power shell

Tags: .net, excel, powershell, xlsx

I have an .xlsx which have the following:-

1. Stored locally inside C drvie
2. contains 5 sheets
3. One sheet named as "Info", contain rows and columns **without tables**. first row represents the headers with filters, and the final row contain totals
4. i need to read the data of the excel sheet named "Info" using Power shell

so can anyone advice on this please?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I tried the Import-Excel, but it did not work for me.

here is a sample Excel sheet with 3 columns and 2 rows:-

[image]

now when i write this script, i got nothing:-

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> [array]$Data = Import-Excel -Path d:\Booking.xlsx -ImportColumns @(1,2,3,4,5) -StartRow 2

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ForEach ($D in $Data) {
   
      Write-Host $D.WO 
}
```

also the count = 1 although i have 2 rows:-

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $Data.Count
1
```

any advice?

Comment: And where are you blocked? As starting point, I would type "read excel in powershell" in my favourite search engine.

Comment: Have a look at `Import-Excel` really easy to use

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon i tried it but not sure how i can programmatic read the rows? as seems the Import-excel will open the data in a grid

Comment: @Pac0 could not find the related scripts to start with

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon lease check my edit

Comment: You say the workbook has 5 worksheets.  Try also specifying the worksheet name `Import-Excel -Path d:\Booking.xlsx -ImportColumns @(1,2,3,4,5) -WorkSheetName Info`     Remove `-StartRow 2` if you are adding that to skip the header row.  The header row should be included which will be used as the property names.  Also try first without saving it with `$Data =`.  The data should just output to the screen so you can see that it works

Answer (score 0):

the Import-Excel module detects rows with filters as your headers automatically. All that is wrong with your command is that the parameter -StartRow 2 should be 1. You can omit -StartRow completely as the module chooses 1 automatically. Choosing the work sheet can be done adding the parameter -WorksheetName.
The following script will work if I understood you right.

```
$Data = Import-Excel -Path d:\Booking.xlsx -WorksheetName Info
ForEach-Object {$Data.WO}
```